# Regarding how to limit the number of characters entered in sumernote

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, summernote

I am using summernote in my app.
I want to limit the number of characters that can be entered in the text input area. Therefore, I have included processing to limit the number of characters in the onPaste, onKeydown, and onKeyup events, as shown in this source code.
With this processing, I am able to limit the number of characters that can be entered as expected for normal keyboard input.
However, there is a problem when inserting links.
In the Insert Link modal, the "Text to display" allows the user to enter an arbitrary string of characters, but does not limit the number of characters for each individual text entry.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.20/summernote-lite.min.css" integrity="sha512-ZbehZMIlGA8CTIOtdE+M81uj3mrcgyrh6ZFeG33A4FHECakGrOsTPlPQ8ijjLkxgImrdmSVUHn1j+ApjodYZow==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.20/summernote-lite.min.js" integrity="sha512-lVkQNgKabKsM1DA/qbhJRFQU8TuwkLF2vSN3iU/c7+iayKs08Y8GXqfFxxTZr1IcpMovXnf2N/ZZoMgmZep1YQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.20/lang/summernote-ja-JP.min.js" integrity="sha512-hpUqToD3dE5r5L85PTHtgEJCOjWhYUoFoih5BQLcwU9yfqb4K8cFTgj7Prd28oRGAGmFR/FqJoePYM/vnKz/0Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="summernote-input">
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <span id= "char-count"> 0 </span><span>/10</span>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function summernoteSettings(inputArea, charCountOutput, charCountLimit) {
        this.toolbar = [ ['insert', ['link']],];
        this.callbacks = {
            onPaste: function (e) {
                var bufferText = ((e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('Text');
                e.preventDefault();

                var t = e.currentTarget.innerText;
                if( t.trim().length + bufferText.length >= charCountLimit){
                    var pasteLength = charCountLimit - t.trim().length;
                    document.execCommand('insertText', false, bufferText.substring(0, pasteLength));
                }else{
                    document.execCommand('insertText', false, bufferText);
                }

                var tafter = e.currentTarget.innerText;
                charCountOutput.text(tafter.trim().length);
            },
            onKeydown: function (e) {
                var t = e.currentTarget.innerText;
                charCountOutput.text(t.trim().length);

                if (t.trim().length >= charCountLimit) {
                    if (e.keyCode != 8 &&                           // 8:BackSpace    
                        !(e.keyCode >= 37 && e.keyCode <= 40) &&    // 37:←,38:↑,39:→,40:↓
                        e.keyCode != 46 &&                          // 46:Delete,
                        !(e.keyCode == 88 && e.ctrlKey) &&          // 88:X
                        !(e.keyCode == 67 && e.ctrlKey)){           // 67:C
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            },
            onKeyup: function (e) {
                var t = e.currentTarget.innerText;
                charCountOutput.text(t.trim().length);
            },
        };

        this.inputArea = inputArea;
        this.charCountOutput = charCountOutput;
        this.charCountLimit = charCountLimit;
    };

    $('#summernote-input')
        .summernote(new summernoteSettings(
            $('#summernote-input'),
            $('#char-count'),
            10 ));

</script>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIazT.png)

I am considering the following two countermeasures, but do not know how to implement them.

1. disable text input to "Text to display" in the link insertion modal.
2. Receive the text entered into "Text to display" in an event when the link insertion modal is closed, and limit the number of characters.

How can these measures be implemented?
Or is there any other way to limit the number of characters?